# How do I change physical path of virtual directory in IIS6 through command line?

Tags: iis-6, command-line-interface, virtualdirectories

I'm looking for a way to change the physical path of a virtual directory in IIS6.  Basically, the IIS6 version of this IIS7 call

```
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set VDIR 
    "Default Web Site/MySite/" "/physicalPath:c:\NewPath"
```

Is there a way to do this or do I have to delete the virtual directory and recreate it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question today: "how do you change the path to an IIS6 vdir using the command line?"

My solution was to make my own vbs. To use it just pass the vdir name and path. So if I had a vdir called "Web" and wanted to change the path to "d:\theNewPath\to\Website", then I would run the following command in the command prompt:

```
updateVDirPath web d:\theNewPath\to\Website
```

Also, to check the path of the Vdir, just pass the vdir name:

```
updateVDirPath web
```

So here are the contents to updateVDirPath.vbs

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 or WScript.Arguments.Count > 2  Then
    WScript.Echo "To check the vDirs path, call updateVDirPath <vDir>" & vbCrLf & "To update the vDir's path, call updateVDirPath <vDir> <newPath>"
Else
    set providerObj = GetObject("winmgmts://localhost/root/MicrosoftIISv2") 
    set IIsWebVirtualDirSettingObj = providerObj.get("IIsWebVirtualDirSetting='W3SVC/1/ROOT/" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "'") 

    If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
        WScript.Echo "Current path is: " & IIsWebVirtualDirSettingObj.Path
    Else
        IIsWebVirtualDirSettingObj.Path = WScript.Arguments(1)
        IIsWebVirtualDirSettingObj.Put_ () 
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use adsutil.vbs for this. It should be in c:\inetpub\adminscripts\

The command line is:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC1/<WebSiteNum>/Root/<Vdirname>/Path "<new physical path>"
```

Comment: Since appcmd was not installed on Strop's server, it is likely that adsutil was also not installed, as they both rely on IIS 6 Metabase compatibility components under IIS7.

Comment: He specifically stated he is on IIS6 though, where appcmd doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the same command in IIS7, as long as you have installed the [IIS6 management compatibility components](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397374.aspx) (these are not installed by default, but can be added via the Add/Remove Windows Features Wizard or the Server Manager tool).

Alternatively, you can directly modify the web.config file in the parent folder (or possibly higher up the tree) where the virtual folder was defined.